# Average CPI of a processor

Tags: cpu-architecture, processor

I understand that CPI can be calculated by clock cycles over instructions. Although I am kind of at an impasse here and need some help. I am trying to find the average CPI of a processor where 25% of the instructions take 1 cycle to execute, 45% take 2 cycles, 15% take 3 cycles, 10% take 4 cycles, and 5% take 5 cycles. Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the total number of instructions is `n`.

| Instruction type | CPI | Instruction count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 0.25 * n |
| B | 2 | 0.45 * n |
| C | 3 | 0.15 * n |
| D | 4 | 0.10 * n |
| E | 5 | 0.05 * n |

Average CPI = (total clock cycles) / (total number of instructions):

```
 (0.25n * 1 + 0.45n * 2 + 0.15n * 3 + 0.10n * 4 + 0.05n * 5) / n
= (0.25 * 1 + 0.45 * 2 + 0.15 * 3 + 0.10 * 4 + 0.05 * 5)
```

At this step, you can see that the average CPI is independent of the total number of instructions `n`, given that you know the proportions of each type of instructions.

So you could have skipped all the above steps and calculate the average CPI directly as follows:

```
= (0.25 * 1 + 0.45 * 2 + 0.15 * 3 + 0.10 * 4 + 0.05 * 5)
```

Answer (score -1):

0.25 * 1 + 0.45 * 2 + 0.15 * 3 + 0.1 * 4 + 0.05 * 5

Comment: Okay, so I don't have to account for instructions? I was under the impression that I would have to assume a certain number of instructions. If not, great! I appreciate your response.

Comment: You don't need the exact number of instructions if u have the distribution